# Problem when I'm trying to send a gzip file using MPI_Send

Tags: c++, mpi

I have a problem and I cannot understand what is happening. I'm working in an MPI project , where all the ranks involved compute some simulations, generate an output file and then sends the output files to the master rank. The output file can be compressed or uncompressed, when the files are compressed, the gzip is used.

This is the code I'm using:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <mpi.h>

using namespace std;

const string receivedFile = "~/receivedFile.txt.gz";
const string sendFile = "~/sendFile.txt.gz";
const int BUFFER_SIZE{1024*1024*100};
const int MPI_SEND_FILE_TAG{15};
const int MPI_END_FILE_TAG{16};

void send_file(int i_to_rank, const std::string &s_file_path)
{
    // ====> Open file
    std::ifstream ifs{s_file_path, std::ifstream::binary};

    // ====> Buffer
    char* buffer{new char[BUFFER_SIZE]};

    // ====> Send file
    while( ifs.read(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE) ) {
        MPI_Send( buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, MPI_BYTE,
                  i_to_rank, MPI_SEND_FILE_TAG,
                  MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }

    // ====> Send last block:
    streamsize last_block_size{ifs.gcount()};
    if ( last_block_size > 0 ) {
         MPI_Send( buffer, last_block_size, MPI_BYTE,
                   i_to_rank, MPI_SEND_FILE_TAG,
                   MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }

    // ====> Close file
    ifs.close();

    // ====> Send end
    MPI_Send( &i_to_rank, 1, MPI_INT, i_to_rank, MPI_END_FILE_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    // ====> Free mem
    delete[] buffer;
}

void receive_file(int i_from_rank, const std::string &s_file_path )
{
    // ====> Output file
    std::ofstream ofs{s_file_path, std::ofstream::binary};

    // ====> Receive file       
    while ( true ) {
        // ====>  Wait for message of specific rank.
        MPI_Status status{};
        MPI_Probe(i_from_rank, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

        if ( status.MPI_TAG == MPI_SEND_FILE_TAG ) {
            // ====> Get msg size:
            int nbytes{0};
            MPI_Get_count(&status, MPI_BYTE, &nbytes);

            // ====> Get mem
            char* buffer{new char[nbytes]};

            // ====> Get the msg
            MPI_Recv( buffer, nbytes, MPI_BYTE, i_from_rank, MPI_SEND_FILE_TAG,
                       MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);

            // ====> Write content in the output file
            ofs << buffer;

            // ====> Free mem
            delete[] buffer;
        }
        else if ( status.MPI_TAG == MPI_END_FILE_TAG ) {
            int val{};
            MPI_Recv( &val, 1, MPI_INT, i_from_rank, MPI_END_FILE_TAG,
                    MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
            break;
        }
    }

    // ====> Close output file
    ofs.close();
}

int main()
{
    // ====> INit MPI
    MPI_Init(nullptr, nullptr);

    // ====> Get rank ID
    int rankID{};
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rankID);

    // ====> Send/Receive the file
    if ( rankID == 0 ) receive_file(1, receivedFile);
    else send_file(0, sendFile);

    // ====> Finalize MPI
    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

This code works correctly when I'm working with uncompress files, but when I try to send a gzip file the file is not sended.

This is the size of the file I'm sending (with ls -l):

```
 64330254 oct 11 09:28 sendFile.txt.gz
```

And this is the size of the recived file (with ls -l):

```
    8 oct 11 16:24 receivedFile.txt.gz
```

If I try to decompress the gzip file I'm obtaining the following error:

```
gzip -d ~/receivedFile.txt.gz
gzip: ~/receivedFile.txt.gz: unexpected end of file
```

The project is working in a distributed cluster, but the problem happens again if I launch the code in my local Linux machine:

```
mpiexec -n 2 exe
```

Does anyone have some idea about what is happening?

Thank you

Comment: Who generated output.sdf.gz?

Comment: In the mpi project the ranks generate the gzip file using boost and then send them to the master rank using the function send_file. The master rank gets the content of the file and write it in the output file using the function receive_file. When I tried this code the gzip file I'm sending to the other rank was generated using the linux command "gzip output.txt". In both cases, in the project launched in the cluster and in this example, launched in my local environment, I'm getting this issue.

Comment: `receivedFile.txt.gz` is only 8 bytes, which is very suspicious to say the least. Try dumping that file (or at least print its size) **before** on the non root rank (e.g. before sending it) to make sure it was correctly generated. My gut feeling is you are looking at MPI but the root cause is somewhere else.

Comment: I've found the problem. The problem is in the method receive_file when I'm trying to write the received data to the output file. What I'm doing is sending the data in binary mode, but when I am writing the data to the output file I'm using the operator '<<'. The operator '<<' generates a sequence of characters, but I need to write the bytes in binary mode. To solve the problem I change the operator '<<' to the method 'ofs.write (buffer, nbytes);" and now is working correctly.